# How to remove folder named * in unix

Tags: unix

Topic is pretty self explanatory. My script accidentally created this folder and I was amused how puzzled I was how to remove it.

```
find . -type d -not -path "*"
```

Obviously won't do it, since I'll get nothing from the find.

I could do a regex search to match everything else than that folder, but is there another way?

Answer (score 2):

Just use simple quotes:

```
rmdir '*'
```

Simple quotes prevents your shell to expand the star.

You can also use `\` to *de*specialize the star:

```
rmdir \*
```

`\` is used to suppress the *magic* of the following character.